# Passing string value on click of UIButton in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have check many articles for passing value on click of uibutton in ios.
But generally,people make use of tag property as alternate.

But I found follwing solution :

```
 UIButton *btnComLike=[[UIButton alloc] init];

 [btnComLike setFrame:CGRectMake(127, 20, 30, 15)];
 [btnComLike addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCommentLike_click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [btnComLike setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [btnComLike setTitle:@"my any string value" forState:UIControlStateReserved];
```

and handler side :

```
-(void)btnCommentLike_click:(id)sender
{
 NSLog(@"%@",[sender titleForState:UIControlStateReserved]);

}
```

is this feasible solution?Here i think on one is making use this state `UIControlStateReserved`.

or is there is any drawback in use of this technique?

if yes,please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: r u passing button title?

Comment: yes @NANNAV but with UIControlStateReserved state...

Comment: @Downloadmore, reserved means reserved, and apple probably didn't reserve is for you.

Comment: Hey @vikingosegundo here,if I use UIControlStateSelected,then it will be fine..right?

Comment: no, that would be even worse. Dont use any property or field of any UIView — and UIButton is a UIView — to pass around informations. That is a Violation of the Model-View-Controller pattern Cocoa build on.

Comment: btw: I had a look at your profile: you should accept more answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me this solution is like beating up MVC and misusing the poor button.

You should just write the object you want to work with in the action method to an ivar (instance variable, member variable) and access it there.

Your Solution could be also considered illegal, from the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW11):

> `UIControlStateReserved`
>   Control-state flags reserved for internal framework use.

Comment: Yap, XY **and** design problem, gulfed (how possibly can one make two huge conceptional mistakes in 3 lines of code?)